Graph with figures instead of nodes
everyone.
I'm trying to use the Tikz library to create a kind of graph as shown in the picture below (I made the picture in Inkscape). But I need to edit the figure continuously. And for me it's not very productive to edit the figure all the time in Inkscape, save it as a pdf and then insert it into the LaTeX document.

To be more specific, the figure in the image above is made up of

A white background, but with the option of choosing a light gray background,

A graph with 5 nodes (or vertices as they are called) distributed according to the positions (-70.00mm,-35.00mm), (-10.00mm,-30.00mm), (40.00mm,-80.00mm), (30.00mm,-10.00mm), (65.00mm,-40.00mm),

Nodes (or vertices as they are called) are connected by arcs (also called edges, links or lines). The arcs in turn (as you can see in the picture) are accompanied by tags or labels in the form of text.

But as suggested in the picture below, I'd like to place a picture with dimensions of 15mm: 15mm in place of each node. I think that in order to standardize the dimensions of the figures in each node, a scale control would be necessary.


May attempt.
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article} % Set the paper size to A4
\usepackage{tikz} % Import TikZ package for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning} % Load TikZ libraries for arrows and positioning
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Set page margins to 2cm

\begin{document}
    
    % Flexible space to vertically center the figure
    \vspace*{\fill}
    
    \begin{center} % Center the content horizontally
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            % 1) Light gray background of 180mm by 100mm
            \fill[lightgray] (-90mm, -90mm) rectangle (90mm, 10mm);
            
            % 4) Define the style for vertices
            \tikzstyle{vertice} = [
            circle, % Shape of the node
            draw=black, % Outline color
            fill=black, % Fill color
            minimum size=4mm, % Diameter of the node
            inner sep=0pt % No inner padding
            ]
            
            % 2) Define the nodes with specified positions and precise labels
            \node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,5mm)}]above:{\textbf{Node A}}}] (A) at (-70mm, -35mm) {}; % Node A
            \node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,-5mm)}]below:{\textit{Node B}}}] (B) at (-10mm, -30mm) {}; % Node B
            \node[vertice, label={[shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]below left:{Node C}}] (C) at (40mm, -80mm) {}; % Node C
            \node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,5mm)}]above:{Node D}}] (D) at (30mm, -10mm) {}; % Node D
            \node[vertice, label={[shift={(5mm,0mm)}]right:{Node E}}] (E) at (65mm, -40mm) {}; % Node E
            
            % 3) Connect the nodes with curved edges and centralized labels
            % Using bend left and bend right alternately to create smooth curves and avoid overlapping
            
            \draw (A) to [bend left=15] (B) node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB}; % Edge A-B
            \draw (A) to [bend right=15] (C) node[midway, above, sloped] {text AC}; % Edge A-C
            \draw (A) to [bend left=15] (D) node[midway, above, sloped] {text AD}; % Edge A-D
            \draw (A) to [bend right=15] (E) node[midway, above, sloped] {text AE}; % Edge A-E
            
            \draw (B) to [bend left=15] (C) node[midway, below, sloped] {text BC}; % Edge B-C
            \draw (B) to [bend right=15] (D) node[midway, above, sloped] {text BD}; % Edge B-D
            \draw (B) to [bend left=15] (E) node[midway, above, sloped] {text BE}; % Edge B-E
            
            \draw (C) to [bend right=15] (D) node[midway, below, sloped] {text CD}; % Edge C-D
            \draw (C) to [bend left=15] (E) node[midway, below, sloped] {text CE}; % Edge C-E
            
            \draw (D) to [bend right=15] (E) node[midway, above, sloped] {text DE}; % Edge D-E
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{center}
    
    % Flexible space to vertically center the figure
    \vspace*{\fill}
    
\end{document}

I tried using the Tikz package and its libraries. I built the nodes with the \tikzstyle command and its parameters and also the tikzpicture environment.  But as you can see from the picture below and the code, the result was less than expected because the names of the arcs (text AB, text AC, etc.) were not in a position close to the arcs.


Apparently midway doesn't work with to, unlike \path (A)--(B) node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB};.  arc might work.

Try \draw (A) to [bend left=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB} (B);

Use \draw (A) to [bend left=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB} (B);
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} % Set the paper size to A4
\usepackage{tikz} % Import TikZ package for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning} % Load TikZ libraries for arrows and positioning

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  
  % 1) Light gray background of 180mm by 100mm
  \fill[lightgray] (-90mm, -90mm) rectangle (90mm, 10mm);
  
  % 4) Define the style for vertices
  \tikzstyle{vertice} = [
    circle, % Shape of the node
    draw=black, % Outline color
    fill=black, % Fill color
    minimum size=4mm, % Diameter of the node
    inner sep=0pt % No inner padding
  ]
  
  % 2) Define the nodes with specified positions and precise labels
  \node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,5mm)}]above:{\textbf{Node A}}}] (A) at (-70mm, -35mm) {}; % Node A
  \node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,-5mm)}]below:{\textit{Node B}}}] (B) at (-10mm, -30mm) {}; % Node B
  \node[vertice, label={[shift={(-5mm,-3mm)}]below left:{Node C}}] (C) at (40mm, -80mm) {}; % Node C
  \node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,5mm)}]above:{Node D}}] (D) at (30mm, -10mm) {}; % Node D
  \node[vertice, label={[shift={(5mm,0mm)}]right:{Node E}}] (E) at (65mm, -40mm) {}; % Node E
  
  % 3) Connect the nodes with curved edges and centralized labels
  % Using bend left and bend right alternately to create smooth curves and avoid overlapping
  
  \draw (A) to [bend left=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB} (B); % Edge A-B
  \draw (A) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AC} (C); % Edge A-C
  \draw (A) to [bend left=15]  node[midway, above, sloped] {text AD} (D); % Edge A-D
  \draw (A) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AE} (E); % Edge A-E
  
  \draw (B) to [bend left=15] node[midway, below, sloped] {text BC} (C); % Edge B-C
  \draw (B) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text BD} (D); % Edge B-D
  \draw (B) to [bend left=15]  node[midway, above, sloped] {text BE} (E); % Edge B-E
  
  \draw (C) to [bend right=15] node[midway, below, sloped] {text CD} (D); % Edge C-D
  \draw (C) to [bend left=15] node[midway, below, sloped] {text CE} (E); % Edge C-E
  
  \draw (D) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text DE} (E); % Edge D-E
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Remark: The arrows and positioning libraries have not been used and \tikstyle is deprecated

For the bacground, I use the bacground librarie
see Paul Gaborrit's comment and answer
I use a command and the package graphicx

Code
\documentclass{article} % Set the paper size to A4
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/729575/graph-with-figures-instead-of-nodes
\usepackage{tikz} % Import TikZ package for drawing
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning} % Load TikZ libraries for arrows and positioning
\usetikzlibrary {backgrounds}%<-- added
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Set page margins to 2cm

\usepackage{graphicx}%<-- added
%%%%%%%%%%%

\NewDocumentCommand{\putfig}{ m }{
  \includegraphics[width=15mm,height=15mm]{#1}
  }
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  vertice/.style={
  %   % circle, % Shape of the node
  %   % draw=black, % Outline color
  %   % fill=black, % Fill color
  %   minimum size=4mm, % Diameter of the node
    inner sep=0pt, % No inner padding
    },
}
\begin{center} % Center the content horizontally
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  background rectangle/.style={
    draw=gray!50,
    fill=gray!20,
    rounded corners=1ex
    },
  show background rectangle]

% 2) Define the nodes with specified positions and precise labels

\node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,5mm)}]above:{\textbf{Node A}}}] (A) at (-70mm, -35mm) {\putfig{example-image-A}}; % Node A
\node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,-5mm)}]below:{\textit{Node B}}}] (B) at (-10mm, -30mm) {\putfig{example-image-B}}; % Node B
\node[vertice, label={[shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]below left:{Node C}}] (C) at (40mm, -80mm) {\putfig{example-image-C}}; % Node C
\node[vertice, label={[shift={(0mm,5mm)}]above:{Node D}}] (D) at (30mm, -10mm) {\putfig{example-image}}; % Node D
\node[vertice, label={[shift={(5mm,0mm)}]right:{Node E}}] (E) at (65mm, -40mm) {\putfig{example-image}}; % Node E
            
% 3) Connect the nodes with curved edges and centralized labels
% Using bend left and bend right alternately to create smooth curves and avoid overlapping

\draw (A) to [bend left=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB} (B); % Edge A-B
\draw (A) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AC} (C); % Edge A-C
\draw (A) to [bend left=15]  node[midway, above, sloped] {text AD} (D); % Edge A-D
\draw (A) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text AE} (E); % Edge A-E

\draw (B) to [bend left=15] node[midway, below, sloped] {text BC} (C); % Edge B-C
\draw (B) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text BD} (D); % Edge B-D
\draw (B) to [bend left=15]  node[midway, above, sloped] {text BE} (E); % Edge B-E

\draw (C) to [bend right=15] node[midway, below, sloped] {text CD} (D); % Edge C-D
\draw (C) to [bend left=15] node[midway, below, sloped] {text CE} (E); % Edge C-E

\draw (D) to [bend right=15] node[midway, above, sloped] {text DE} (E); % Edge D-E

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}



The idea here is to compute an arc (radius) connecting two points, using the fact the the chord length for a arc is given by $2r\sin(\theta/2)$.
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}% or \path ($(B)-(A)$);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xlen}{\ylen}% distance from (A) to (B)
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\radius}{0.5*veclen(\xlen,\ylen)/sin(20)}% (115-75)/2=20
      \global\let\radius=\radius
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \draw[red] (A) arc[start angle=115, end angle=75, radius=\radius]
      node[midway, above, sloped] {text AB}; % Edge A-B

